# Not able to display data in tree format using nested ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have written this HTML to display my data in tree format, but its not working as expected. What is the issue here.

I know I can use custom directive to do that, but I just want it to show in very basic format. Also writing directive for this will be very tricky.

```
<div data-ng-cloak data-ng-show="rootNode.children.totalAvailable > 0">
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Tree Form</th>
        </tr>


        <tr data-ng-repeat="parent in rootNode.children.items">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{parent.displayName}}
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr data-ng-repeat="firstChild in parent.children.items">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{firstChild.displayName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="secondChild in firstChild.children.items">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{secondChild.displayName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tr> 
            </tr>       
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Tree structure I want to display is as follows

```
Parent 1
    Child 1.0
        SecondChild 1.0.1
        SecondChild 1.0.2
        SecondChild 1.0.3
    Child 1.1
        SecondChild 1.1.1
        SecondChild 1.1.2
        SecondChild 1.1.3

Parent 2
    Child 2.0
        SecondChild 2.0.1
        SecondChild 2.0.2
        SecondChild 2.0.3
    Child 2.1
        SecondChild 2.1.1
        SecondChild 2.1.2
        SecondChild 2.1.3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that Angular knows the correct pluralization. (firstChild -> firstChildren, if not try firstChilds). Also does it need to be in a table.

```
<div data-ng-cloak data-ng-model="items" data-ng-show="rootNode.children.totalAvailable > 0">
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <th>Tree Form</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="parent in items">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{parent.displayName}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="firstChild in parent.firstChildren">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{firstChild.displayName}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="secondChild in firstChild.secondChildren">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{secondChild.displayName}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Or not in a table.

```
<div data-ng-cloak data-ng-controller="NameController" data-ng-show="rootNode.children.totalAvailable > 0">
    <ol data-ng-model="items">
        <li data-ng-repeat="parent in items">
            <span data-ng-bind="parent.displayName"></span>
            <ol>
                <li data-ng-repeat="firstChild in parent.firstChildren">
                    <span data-ng-bind="firstChild.displayName"></span>
                    <ol>
                        <li data-ng-repeat="secondChild in firstChild.secondChildren">
                            <span data-ng-bind="secondChild.displayName"></span>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is enough or if you want me to make a Plunker or something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a silly suggestion but why don't you use a CSS `text-indent` depending on child level? The whole idea of `tr` in `tr` seems to be overcomplicated and poorly maintainable

Comment: Main issue here is I am not able to use ng-repeat in nested fashion

Comment: your ng-repeats looks fine, but the output html will be invalid

Comment: Why my HTML will be invalid. Please be specific. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: for a starter as far as i remember valid elements in `tr` are `td` and `th`